# Codeigniter won't run my index functions

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

Is it correct that the index function in Codeigniter can be called like this: http://example.com/page ?

How comes, when I try to go to this URL I get a 404 message, but it works fine when I use it like this: http://example.com/page/index ?

Comment: You may need to set your routes.

Comment: I did. My routes look like this:

`$route['(:any)'] = 'template_loader/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'template_loader/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0):

I will give it ago, but not much code to go on. If you have not set your route you need to.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "folder/controller";

$route['page'] = "folder/controller/index";`
```

Then you should work with http://www.example.com/page

**Put** `$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com/";` **And** `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Make sure you have .htaccess set.

**Example** `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: My routes look like this:

`$route['(:any)'] = 'template_loader/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'template_loader/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`

And I copy/pasted your htaccess code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: By the way I can reach www.example.com but I can't reach www.example.com/my_controller without index behind it.

Comment: I would suggest watching a couple of tutorials on how its done. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hRNFgSLLAQ and route user guide. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html and http://forum.codeigniter.com/

Comment: Also you can download 5 htaccess files for codeigniter here to try http://www.insiderclub.org/downloads